# Can not upload image in library imagekitio-react version 2.0.0 in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, imagekit

my project is using library imagekitio-react version 1.1.1 and it's work correctly. But now i want to limit image uploads to less than 5mb and version 1.1.1 IkUpLoad cannot support this.
I see version 2.0.0 have onUploadStart in  component.
So, if i use 2.0.0 version, it throw error

```
Run upload error TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
    at eval (imagekitio-react.umd.js?26af:213:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at generateSignatureToken (imagekitio-react.umd.js?26af:210:1)
    at request (imagekitio-react.umd.js?26af:195:1)
    at ImageKit.upload (imagekitio-react.umd.js?26af:327:1)
```

and can not upload image.

What can i do now to check size of image file upload using IKUpload here

```
<IKUpload
        onChange={() => {
          setLoadingImage(true)
        }}
        onError={onError}
        onSuccess={onSuccess}
      />
```

or any solution here.
Many thanks. I'm stuck with this too long.